# How to limit returns in a multiple line EditText?

Tags: android, enter

I put a multiline `EditText` in my application. The problem is that if the user presses enter, the `EditText` often collides with the icons in my application. I want to avoid that.

I wanted to know how to make it so that the user can only press enter 5 times and no more?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Is this a layout issue or an issue with EditText?

Comment: Show us your code, so that we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restrict the height of an EditText, you can use the maxLines attribute

```
<EditText
...
android:maxLines="5"
...
/>
```